# What are the advantages of loading DLLs dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dynamic-loading

Looking for the advantages of loading DLLs dynamically as opposed to letting your application load the DLLs by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One advantage is for supporting a plugin architecture.

Suppose for example you want to write a service that performs different types of tasks on a scheduled basis. What those tasks are doing, isn't actually relevant to your core service which is just there to kick them off at the right time. And, it's more than likely you want to add support to do other types of tasks in the future (or another developer might want to). In that scenario, by implementing a plugin approach, it allows you to drop in more (compatible by interface) dlls which can be coded independently of the core service. So, adding in support for a new task does not require a new build/deployment of the whole service. If a particular task needs to change, just that dll needs to be redeployed and then automatically picked up.

It also requires other developers to not be concerned with the service themselves, they just need to know what interface to implement so it can be picked up.

Comment: What if your system is a non-plugin architecture type system. What other advantages would their be?

Comment: The only times I've done it is within a plugin architecture tbh. I can't think of another reason why else I would consider it otherwise. Maybe some sort of security purpose - i.e. only load dlls that give the functionality a certain user is allowed access to. But tbh I'm not even sure that would be a valid approach to take over just controlling other ways in code!

Comment: What about performance? Does it matter that you have a DLL loaded when in actual fact you would only be using it rarely?

Comment: It would only use a bit more memory to have it loaded. If you load it dynamically at the time of use, and then unloaded straight after, then I think that will be a bigger performance overhead - it has the extra steps to perform each time it's used (even if only rarely) - though I have no hard stats to quantify performance.

Comment: Seems to be the only advantage by the looks of it...Thanks.

Comment: May I ask how the new .dll's are deployed? is it a manual copy and paste in the right location? I'm having hard time understanding this part

Answer (score 2):

We use this architecture for our processing applications to handle differences that our different customers require.  Each DLL has a similar structure and implements the same interface and entry method "Process()".  We have an XML file that defines which class to load based on the customer and whether there are more methods besides process that needs to be called.  Performance should not be an issue until your transaction count gets very high.

Answer (score 1):

Loading Shared Objects dynamically is the mechanism for allowing plugins *ad hoc* to running applications. Without plugins a modular application would have to be put together at link-time or compile-time (look at the code of nginx).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about C#/.NET so in this world dynamic DLL loading requires advanced programming skills. This could compensate all the potential benefits of dynamic DLL loading. You would simply have to write a lot 'low level' code.

In C++/Win32 I often have to load a DLL dynamically when this DLL has some new API function which is not available on older operating systems. In this case I need to ensure the availability of this API at runtime. I cannot just link against this DLL because it will cause application loading errors on legacy operating systems.

As mentioned, you could also have some benefits in a plugin-based environment. In this case you would have more control on your resources if loading DLLs dynamically. Essentially COM is a good example of dynamic DLL handing.

Answer (score 1):

If you only load the DLLs you need then the startuptime of the application should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to load DLL's dynamically is for robustness.

It is possible to load a DLL into what is known as an AppDomain. An Appdomain is basically a sand box container that you can put things into (Either portions of DLL's or whole EXEs) to run in isolation, but within your application.

Unless you call into a type contained within an AppDomain, it has no way to interact with your application.

So, if you have a dodgy third party DLL, or a DLL that you don't otherwise have the source code for, you can load it into an AppDomain to keep it isolated from your main application flow.

The end result is that if the third party DLL throws a wobbly, only the appdomain, and not your entire application is affected.